# Windows store app 8.1 shows black screen on windows 10 devices

Tags: windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

We are developing windows store app targeting both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. This application works fine on windows 8.1 surface/PC. When we install it on a Windows 10 device, it does not. Though it installs without any issue. Once launched it shows the splash screen, but then it shows blank, black screen.

Please guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little confusion. You mean it works on 8.1 but not on windows 10? Or it works when deployed from VS but not when deployed from store? Do you have any extended splash screen?

Comment: Just notice, from the title, it's happening on windows 10 devices. I think you need to try to simplify your project and get the repro code and steps to help others better understand your scenario. It's really hard to guess what happened.

Comment: Hi the application works on windows 8.1, I am developing project on windows 8.1 installing AppPackage to other devices 8.1 and 10 as said above. Sorry I forgot to mention that this issue comes for me when I give apppackage of project to install on other devices for testing.

Comment: Have you ever tried to debug the project on windows 10 and see what happened? And I cannot guess what you are doing in your app. So more details will help to let me understand.

Comment: Not tried on debug on windows 10, as I am checking this on non developer PC.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 should execute the same as Windows 8. I assume you have upgraded your app to be a UWP app? If not, it should still work. Next, be sure you are running the final release (build 10240) of Windows 10, prior to that build Windows 8 apps did not always work. Finally, have you put a breakpoint in the constructor of your first page? If this breakpoint is being hit, then your page is loading and just not showing. My next step would be to ensure the Frame is property getting set to Windows.Current.Content properly. Since it works in Windows 8 this is unlikely, but it would be my next step. If all of those check out, I would likely determine that the Frame is being hidden, occluded or replaced somehow in my code.

Then, I would check this:

The compilation conditional statements of #IF are common in Windows 8 apps. I would make sure that I don't have an #IF/#ELIF and don't have an #ELSE condition would handle UWP. I realize this is esoteric, but you only gave me a concept to go on, not real code. Given that, those would be my steps. The code in Windows 10 is causing your page either 1) not to load or 2) to be hidden. Even though the code is the "same" the execution is clearly not.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, I've found that if you fullscreen or resize the app while on the splash screen is displayed the MainPage loads.

I've run the app in Visual Studio on a Windows 10  machine and it seems we never hit `async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`.